# Вывести value в label

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Есть такой код на vue

```
<el-option  label="Наличные" value="149"></el-option>
<el-option  label="Безналичные"  value="150"></el-option>
```

Вывожу данные

```
$arFields = [
"IBLOCK_ID" => 89,
"NAME" => 'Платеж от '.($_GET['typeOp']),
];
```

**Проблема:** не могу вывести значение `label` то есть "Наличные или Безналичные" он тянет значение `value`, как вывести значение `label='?'`

Comment: Приведите минимальный воспроизведимый пример и мы постараемся найти ошибку

Comment: вывод осуществляется по тому что лежит в value, то есть 150 или же 149

Comment: Значения берутся из базы? Если да, то можете отправлять запрос, дабы получить тип платежа (нал, безнал). Если нет, то откуда 149 и 150? Если хардкод, тогда проверяйте через условие.

Comment: значения берутся и формы выше

Comment: Как вы отправляете форму свою?

Comment: Как вариант - добавьте скрытый input c name="label" и посредством js добавляйте ему значение label'a выбранного option'a